# Animate on min-height property in Angular way

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

**html**

```
<body ng-controller="SearchController as searchCtrl">
    <div>
      <button data-cover="{{searchCtrl.cover.open}}">opener</button>
    </div>
    <div class="slider">
      <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
      <button data-cover="{{searchCtrl.cover.open}}">closer</button>
    </div>
  </body>
```

**css**

```
.slider {
  position:fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  background: white;
    max-height: 0;
}
.slider.open {
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

**javascript**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('SearchController', function() {
  var searchCtrl = this;
  searchCtrl.cover= {};
  searchCtrl.cover.open = false;  //initially cover is closed
});

app.directive('cover', cover);

function cover(){

  var directive = {
    scope: '=',
    link : function(scope, ele, attrs){
      var slider = angular.element(document.querySelector('.slider'));
      ele.bind('click', function(){
        if(scope.searchCtrl.cover.open == true){
          scope.searchCtrl.cover.open=false;
          slider.removeClass("open");
        } else{
          scope.searchCtrl.cover.open = true;
          slider.addClass("open");
        }
      });
    }
  }

  return directive;

}
```

I wrote a directive to open and close a cover from bottom to top which should occupy the full height. I was able to do that. Now i want to add animations (cover should open slowly form bottom). For cover the initial max-height is "zero", later when i click "open" button, i make min-height to "100%". CSS3 transitions doesn't work on min-height property(only on max-height). I am not using jquery, so i cannot use Jquery animate function in the directive. How can i do this in angular way

Answer (score 0):

In angular to update style you can just use your slider variable like this :

```
slider = document.querySelector('.slider');
slider.style.transition = 'all .3s ease';
slider.style.height = window.innerHeight + 'px';
```

or translate to bottom

```
slider = document.querySelector('.slider');
slider.style.transition = 'all .3s ease';
slider.style.transform = 'translate3d(0,100px,0)';
```

with many adjustement you can do it !

PS: you can animate line-height property :)